# Time Between First and Second Records SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the time between the first and second records. My thought was to add a ranking for each record and then do a calculation on RN 2 - RN 1. I'm struggling to actually get the subquery to do RN2-RN1.

SAMPLE Data:

| user_id | date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 698998737289929044 | 2021-04-08 11:27:38 | 1 |
| 698998737289929044 | 2021-04-08 12:20:25 | 2 |
| 698998737289929044 | 2021-04-01 13:23:59 | 3 |
| 732850336550572910 | 2021-03-23 06:13:25 | 1 |
| 598830651911547855 | 2021-03-11 11:56:53 | 1 |

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  date,
  row_number() over(partition by user_id order by date) as RN
FROM event_table
GROUP BY user_id, date
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not 100% clear to me what exactly you need.

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry, it is just a table with user_id and date. Updated with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the result with itself to get the first and second row.

For example:

```
with
q as (
  -- your query here
)
select
  f.user_id,
  f.date,
  s.date - f.date as diff
from q f
left join q s on s.user_id = f.user_id and s.rn = 2
where f.rn = 1
```